# Create a trigger for discount

Tags: sql, db2, database-trigger

I want to create a trigger that will update the price in the table ticket according to discount from table audience into the table Ticket. however i amd having errors when inserting into

Table Ticket :

```
create table Ticket(
Ticket_ID integer not null,
Class_Name varchar(50),
Payment_Method varchar(60),
Audience_ID integer,
Seating_Number varchar(20),
Price integer,

primary key(Ticket_ID),
foreign key(Class_Name) references Class)
foreign key(Audience_ID) references Audience,
foreign key(Seating_Number) references Seating);
```

Table Audience

```
CREATE TABLE AUDIENCE
(Audience_ID integer not null,
 Audience_Age integer,
 Audience_Type varchar (50),
 Discount Decimal(7,2),
 Primary key (Audience_ID)
 );



CREATE Trigger Audience_Type
    AFTER INSERT ON AUDIENCE
    FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL
        UPDATE AUDIENCE
        SET Audience_Type = (SELECT Price FROM TICKET) &&
        (Price-(Price*Discount))
        WHERE AUDIENCE.Discount = TICKET.Price
```

Comment: What errors? Don't see any errors.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't updating Ticket table, you are updating Audience table. 
Try :

```
CREATE Trigger T_name
AFTER INSERT ON AUDIENCE
FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL
    UPDATE Ticket   -- here you should update Ticket table 
    SET price = Price-(Price*:new.Discount)
    WHERE ticket.AUDIENCE_id= AUDIENCE.AUDIENCE_id
```

Read a little bit about :new and :old when you work with trigger. Besides, this will not update the ticket table if you update the audience table. You can say "after insert or update ...."

Comment: AUDIENCE.DISCOUNT" is not valid in the context where it is used -- Got this error

Comment: try to update the price to e.g. 100 (...  SET price = 100 ...), and see if it goes

Comment: right now it is working after i removed AUDIENCE from AUDIENCE.AUDIENCE_id but it is showing wrong values , it calculates all of the values(it is supposed to evaluate where audience type is student only).

Comment: Note that i have also changed discount from Int to decimal